# Configure env variables with Azure variables in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a vue project deploying in azure devops platform. I have configured some variables in the realease and I would like to use them in my project.

I have an example with Angular project in my company and they use env.js with this code:

```
  (function (window) {
     window.__env = window.__env || {};
     window.__env.clientID = 'app-id';
  }(this));
```

But I have not idea how to replicate it

app-id is this variable:

[AZURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3CQk.png)

I would like to use azure's variables in my project. I have tried it like this:

[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n6zr.png)

Inside ${} put the name of azure's variable but it does not work

[UPDATE]

I have `.env.production` file with this:
`VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID=#{client-id}#` -> this client-id is a variable inside azure https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3CQk.png one of the variables I have crossed out.

And I have a `vsts-ci.yml` file and I have added this:

```
##### REPLACE TOKENS #####
  - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
    displayName: "Replace tokens"
    inputs:
      targetFiles: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.env.production"
```

I would like to access by `process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID` in my vue component and I would like to obtain the value inside azure variables.

Now I have deployed this code and pipeline returns:

```
##[warning]  variable not found: client-id
```

So I have not idea how to connect it.

Comment: It's specific to your project setup, not Vue. If you're using Vue CLI then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440341/how-to-load-azure-app-service-application-settings-into-vue

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, but I have this file (.env), and I don't know how to connect it with azure variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task to fulfill your use case. In your case you can replace them with the variables in the `.env` file. From the usage example:

> [image]

Comment: thanks, but I would like to use azure variables inside the components, I'm not sure with this is possible (for example to define the API url or de MSAL cliend ID) @Sibtain

Comment: the variables can be referred in any file provided that you have added them as part of the `Target files` in replace token task

Comment: @OiHane, DevOps variable will be automatically mapped as environment variable in release pipeline, but **except for secret type variable**. In your pipeline, there is no relationship between secret variable(from variable group), .env, and function defined. as @Sibtain suggested, after you replace the value from variable group with `replacetoken` task, you can access the environment variables in function code with the global `process.env` object(doc [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)), like `process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID`.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT thanks for you answer, I'm going to try it. But I don't know why with angular we didn't need to put replace tokens, but with vue yes... (sorry I'm new on this)

Comment: It doesn't work... :(

Comment: @Oihane can you edit your answer and share what exactly you tried and what's the challenge you are getting while using this task?

Comment: @Sibtain I have update my question :)

Comment: The warning `variable not found: client-id` indicates your variable name is not correct. The task would like to search `client-id` named variable but it's not found, check your variable group to confirm the variable name used.

Comment: @Oihane, i see you have fixed the variable name in another [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366307/use-azure-devops-release-variables-group-in-vue-application), and confirmed replace token is working for you.  It's recommended that you also [mark it answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for this ticket as it's resolved. Thanks.